# Build the XML Document object using JDBC ResultSet

Tags: java, xml, jdbc

We are getting Cursor in JDBC ResultSet object.Now i have to build the complex XML document object using ResultSet. Currently i have been building document object in procedural way.

Now is there any Object oriented way to simplify the xml document building logic.so that it can accommodate the future changes also.

I have following structure of xml document,

```
<Response>
    <BillingInformation>
        <BillingID>
            <Identifier>
            </Identifier>
        </BillingID>
        <BillInfo>
            <ID>
                <Identifier>
                </Identifier>
            </ID>
            <BillingCustomerName>
            </BillingCustomerName>
            <AlternateID>
                <Identifier>
                </Identifier>
                <Type>
                </Type>
            </AlternateID>
            <PostalAddress>
                <ID>
                    <Identifier>
                    </Identifier>
                    <Type>
                    </Type>
                </ID>
                <StreetAddress>
                    <AddressContent>
                    </AddressContent>
                    <AddressContent>
                    </AddressContent>
                </StreetAddress>
                <City>
                </City>
                <State>
                </State>
                <Country>
                </Country>
                <Zip>
                </Zip>
                <Status>
                </Status>
            </PostalAddress>
            <Contact>
                <ContactId>
                    <Identifier>
                    </Identifier>
                    <Type>
                    </Type>
                </ContactId>
                <AlternateContactId>
                    <Identifier>
                    </Identifier>
                    <Type>
                    </Type>
                </AlternateContactId>
                <ContactName>
                    <FirstLastName>
                        <FirstName>
                        </FirstName>
                        <LastName>
                        </LastName>
                    </FirstLastName>
                </ContactName>
            </Contact>
            <Status>
            </Status>
        </BillInfo>
    </BillingInformation>
</Response>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the WebRowSet Class to accomplish this in the past. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/WebRowSet.html

You might find it the easiest approach

Answer (score 2):

Use JPA and JAXB. With JPA you will read (map) DB records into BillingInformation Java object(s), then marshal it to XML with JAXB.

Answer (score 2):

[XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) allow to map Objects to XML.
You have to create a Object hierarchy like your XML and anotate the classes with node names.

Works well with simple XML structures, as shown here: http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html.

Comment: Why introduce an external dependency when the JAXB (JSR-222) implementation included in the JDK/JRE can easily handle the same use case?  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html